# Capybara Cucumber test fail to find xpath when browser is minimized

Tags: cucumber, rspec2, capybara

I'm running a scenario where form fields are automatically filled in with invalid values which trigger some javascripts to show warnings under each incorrectly filled field when I blur. 
The test passes when the browser is in focus. It finds the xpath with the "expected warning" that I pass. But if I minimize or just click on another application, it fails to find the xpath.

I'm running Firefox 3.6 (going to update it soon) and the way I'm doing to find the xpath is by using "page.should have_xpath(xpath)"

Does anyone have any idea how what might solve this? It's really important for me to run it with the browser minimized.

**Edit** and alternative solution:
I guess the timing issue that occurs in events such as blur followed by finding a certain xpath in a minimized browser inherent to the driver itself. Therefore, I decided to run the tests in a Virtual Frame Buffer using xvfb in Linux and it seems to be working really well. I'm planning on applying this to be triggered by Hudson/Jenkins whenever a change is committed.

Comment: Why are you interacting with the browser when web-automation is running? These test should be left to themselves, preferably automated, so one can't accidentally change interactions.

Comment: I'm not interacting with it. You might have miss read "when I blur" when I actually mean the browser does it by itself. The thing is when I'm developing the scenarios on my dev machine, I want to be able to continue developing. The fact that the browser is not the selected program shouldn't interfere with Capybara trying to find the xpath on the page. It works with EVERYTHING else except page.should have_xpath(xpath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a timing issue? Perhaps if the browser isn't frontmost and maximised, the rendering is not happening quickly enough for the content be present when Capybara checks for it.

Also: How are you triggering the blur event?

Comment: I'm almost certain it's a timing issue. The blur event is being done like this:
def blur(field)
   page.execute_script("$('##{field}').blur();")
end

Should I do it another way?

Comment: Perhaps use fire_event? http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2009/01/24/how-i-learned-to-love-seleniums-fireevent/

Comment: Although it did the same thing as execute_script(), the same problem happened when the browser was minimized. :(